# Rollup.js: undefined objects in external dependencies

Tags: javascript, rollupjs

I recently started playing with rollupjs. After configuring everything as per available docs and bundling things up, I got many errors from my external libraries about undefined objects. This sort of errors: `Cannot read property 'parse' of undefined` coming from crypto-js.
It complains about this line in the code: `var ciphertext = Base64.parse(openSSLStr)`. So `Base64` is undefined. I have few errors like this from different external libraries bundled in.

I use a handful of external dependencies:
chart.js,
crypto-js,
mithril,
moment,
pluralize

All of them work perfectly with `jspm`. I decided to try rollup to speed things up as jspm is soooo slow at the moment. Now half of my external dependencies stopped working. I get "undefined things" and "...not a function" kind of errors coming from external libraries only.

What could possibly be the cause of it?

This is my rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import npm from 'rollup-plugin-npm';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

    export default {
      entry: 'app/scripts/application/main.js',
      format: 'cjs',
      plugins: [
        npm({
          jsnext: true,
          main: true,
        }),
        babel({
          exclude: 'node_modules/**',
          presets: [ 'es2015-rollup' ],
        }),
        commonjs(),
        uglify(),
      ],
      dest: 'static/js/application.js',
    };
```

Let me know if any other details are needed.

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I've done a simple tests-reproduction bundling those libraries that generate errors in my application.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "minion",
  "private": true,
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "es2015-rollup"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chart.js": "^1.0.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.6",
    "mithril": "^0.2.2-rc.1",
    "moment": "^2.11.1",
    "pluralize": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015-rollup": "^1.1.1",
    "rollup-plugin-babel": "^2.3.9",
    "rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^2.2.0",
    "rollup-plugin-npm": "^1.3.0",
    "rollup-plugin-uglify": "^0.1.0"
  }
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import npm from 'rollup-plugin-npm';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import uglify from 'rollup-plugin-uglify';

export default {
  entry: 'app/main.js',
  format: 'cjs',
  plugins: [
    npm({
      jsnext: true,
      main: true,
    }),
    babel({
      exclude: 'node_modules/**',
      presets: [ 'es2015-rollup' ],
    }),
    commonjs(),
    //uglify(),
  ],
  dest: 'static/js/app.js',
}
```

main.js

```
import Application from './application'
import pluralize from 'pluralize'


var text = Application.run()

console.log(`Testing encryption: ${text}`)
console.log(`Testing pluralization: ${pluralize('person')}`)
```

application.js

```
import crypt from 'crypto-js'

var Application = {
    run() {
      var ciphertext = crypt.AES.encrypt('Testing encryption...', 'password')
      var bytes  = crypt.AES.decrypt(ciphertext.toString(), 'password')
      return bytes.toString(crypt.enc.Utf8)
    }
}

export default Application
```

Running the above will generate the errors.

Comment: Can you produce a minimal reproduction? I tried [here](https://gist.github.com/Rich-Harris/160a65c5c8ce6feb7337) but without luck – without knowing what causes the error it's hard to investigate. My hunch is that it's related to cyclical dependencies in CommonJS modules, which the commonjs plugin might not currently be able to handle.

Comment: I created a simple test which reproduces the bundling errors. I updated my question. Thank you.

Comment: @r.sendecky any updates on this issue?

Comment: I reproduced this issue with the versions of the packages available at the time, then updated them all to the latest and was no longer able to reproduce it—the script ran and produced the expected output. It seems to have been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Just speculating: Maybe is a bug of the rollup and/or crypto.

I have a similar error when trying to run a js function in Node Red, the js is ok when I run it locally but it throws `TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined` when runs remotely.

The only thing that my code have in common with yours is that both uses cryptography, specifically crypto-js 3.1.2 rollup "hmac-sha256.js" and the code is not imported but raw.

Even after deleting the only instance of 'split' yet I can't solve it (but keeps running locally)